# Move computer into ou

Tags: active-directory, subnet

I have a customer that has 4 locations. We have 2 dcs in one of the locations. I want to create a domain that will separate computer objects by location. Sometimes a users will visit another location but that is not that often. Is there a way to have ad automatically detect what subnet/location as computer is connected to and move the computer to the correct ou automatically? Ive read that separating by subnet might be the best bet. What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to move them? Do you want to apply specific Group Policy settings to the computers based on the location they're at? If so, then use Site linked Group Policy Objects. Make sure that you have Active Directory Sites and Services configured correctly with your sites and subnets.

Comment: There are specific printers at each location. I dont want this tied to the user thats logging in but to the computer. I have setup the sites and added the subnets. In each locations OU in users and computers I have created a computers OU for each location. How do I make it so that when a computer joins the domain it moves or creates the computer object by the subnet it is on or the computer name prefix.

Comment: A GPO linked to a site will be applied to computers when they are present at that site.

Comment: Yes. The OP wants to move them to a different OU based on location so I'm assuming he wants to apply GPO settings based on location. Site linked GPO's will do this.